# If file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a code

```
if ["a1 a2" = "a*"]
then
   echo match
else
   echo "a*"
fi
```

that I have typed and the return statement is

a*

main.ksh[3]: [a1 a2: not found [No such file or directory]

I am wondering why this is, I thought the if statement only compared the strings. What does it have to do with files and directories?

Comment: This question is very closely related to [Understand Error Message in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506280/understand-error-message-in-unix).

Answer (score 1):

Spacing issue, you need to do

`if [ "a1 a2" = "a*" ]`

otherwise at least `"a1` will get treated as part of the test operator.

Also to do regex matching, you need to do something like

`if [[ "a1 a2" =~ "a"* ]]`

But note that will match `a` followed by 0 or more characters anywhere in the string, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted something like:

```
if [ "a1 a2" = "`echo a*`" ]
...
```

which is checking whether there are exactly two files (`a1` and `a2`) in the working directory starting by the prefix `a`.