# Understand Error Message in Unix

Tags: unix

I have the following code:

```
# The current working directory
# contains the files a1 a2 b c

files="a*"
if [ "a1 a2" = $files ]
then
    echo match
else
    echo $files
fi
```

and I get the error message is that $ﬁles expands to more than one
word and the if fails.

What does this error message mean?

Comment: This question is very closely related to [if file in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505940/if-file-in-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` operator of the `[ ... ]` command takes a single word as its left operand and a single word as its right operand.

Your variable `$files` contains the names of multiple files, so it expands to multiple words.

Add quotation marks to treat it as a single word:

```
if [ "a1 a2" = "$file" ]
```

But as Jonathan Leffler's comment correctly points out, that still won't work; it avoids the syntax error, but it will never match because `"$file"` expands literally to `"a*"`.

There's a rather convoluted way to do what you appear to be trying to do:

```
if [ "a1 a2" = "$(eval echo $file)" ]
```

Since `$file` isn't quotes, it expands to `a*` which then expands to `a1 a2`, which is multiple words. The `$(command)` construct can be enclosed in double quotes to turn it from multiple words to a single word.

I'm not at all sure that's the best way to do what you're trying to do.

(And I should mention that you accepted this answer while it was still incorrect. You should probably have tried it before doing that. I think it's correct now.)

Comment: With `"$file"`, there won't be any metacharacter expansion, so `if [ "a*" = "$file" ]` would be true, but what you wrote will always be false.